# Java - Retain data type of value while iterating through HashMaps

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, iterator

I am attempting to iterate through a HashMap that contains the following type of data types:

```
HashMap<city, neighbors>
```

A `city` is an object that contains a String value and returns the string upon being called upon. Here is the code that makes up my `city` class:

```
import java.util.*;  
public class city{
  String city;
  public city(String s){
    this.city = s;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return this.city; 
  }
}
```

A `neighbors` is an object that contains an ArrayList of cities. Here is the code that makes up my `neighbors` class:

```
import java.util.*;  
public class neighbors extends ArrayList<city> {
  public neighbors (city[] n) {
    for (city v : n)
      this.add(v); 
  }
}
```

I am attempting to iterate through this hash map using the normal convention of using an iterator like so:

```
    Iterator it = graph.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
          System.out.println("Key :" + pair.getKey()); //prints the city              System.out.println("Value :" + pair.getValue()); //prints the neighbors
          //for (city c: pair.getValue()){
          //  System.out.println("Test... " + c);
          //}
    }
```

The iterator above works well and prints the getKey and getValue statements well. The problem I am having is that I am having difficulty iterating THROUGH the VALUE of the Map.Entry (which is an ArrayList). The for loop that I have commented out is an attempt to accomplish this task. I am realizing that the `getValue()` method returns back an Object, but how can I retain the data type of the Value, which is an ArrayList? Should I include another method in my `neighbors` class that follows the `toString()` strategy from the `city` class? How can I iterate through the neighbors of the HashMap so I can compare them to other values? Please let me know if my question is unclear, and any tips, modifications, or advise will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterized types instead of raw types for the `Iterator` and the `Map.Entry` variables:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<city, neighbors>> it = graph.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<city, neighbors> pair = it.next();
    System.out.println("Key :" + pair.getKey()); //prints the city              
    System.out.println("Value :" + pair.getValue()); //prints the neighbors
    for (city c: pair.getValue()){
        System.out.println("Test... " + c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the Object you're iterating through to neighbors class. Of course that should be preceeded by a type check.

```
neighbors values = (neighbors) pair.getValue();
for (city c: values){
      System.out.println("Test... " + c);
}
```

I've noticed some weird things:

1. You should not have classes starting with lowercase letters (city, neighbors)
2. If the city has just one field called "city" (which is a String), you can just have a String to represent a city.
3. If your neighbors class contains a list of cities which represent just Strings you can simply have a `List<String>` to represent a list of cities.
4. Your map becomes `Map<String, List<String>>` which is much easier to read and you don't need extra classes.

You can iterate like this after having made these changes without a need of a cast.

```
for(String city : graph.keySet()){
    for(String neighbor : graph.get(city)){

    }
}
```